# Crash with no info

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, cocos2d-iphone

Well, while running my iPhone game on my iPhone 4 through Xcode, my app crashed (sometimes does, sometimes doesn't), and when it crashed, Xcode didn't throw me any info. In the log, I could see `(gdb)` written, but nothing else that could help me find the problem.

What could cause such an error? At least it should tell me *something*, no?

Comment: Did you have debug enabled? Try to enable debug and see if you get more info. Run the program in debug mode.

Comment: also, you should add a general exception breakpoint, when you display the breakpoints, at the bottom you will see a '+' , click on that and you will be offered to add the bkpt. Start with objective-C only (Dhension is a snake nest with exceptions :) ).

Comment: Is it a game crash (app vanishes and top view is shown with app icons), or a game freeze ?

Comment: sheesh ... am totally out of focus tonight. In Organizer, Devices, 'choose the device'->Console , there might be a hint in there for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crashes without explanation on the device itself are often due to using up too much memory; the device simply terminates the app when it has requested more memory than available. This is easy to do in game development, with all those images.

Use Instruments to track memory usage, and/or put some good memory management code in the App Delegate methods for memory warnings and always release as much as you can.